# GitHub Actions Workflow: Remote server upgrade / reboot and continue to the next step

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github

I'm in the beginning of developing a workflow yml script. The main idea is to have a manually triggered "remote server" build file, to set up all the necessary applications in a "Host Server" that will later handle docker containers and other workflows will be handles by merge triggers.

Problem I'm facing is with the first step of the server configuration. Manually, I do:

```sh
apt update
apt apt upgrade -y
sudo reboot
```

Wait for the server to reboot (come back online) so it loads the new kernel and continue with the installation.

I'm trying to automate the setup in GitHub Actions Workflow. Up till now, this is how my file looks like:

```yml
name: Host Server Build V1.0.0

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      
      env:
        CONFIG_SERVER_SSH_KEY: '${{ secrets.CONFIG_SERVER_SSH_KEY }}'
        CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP: '${{ secrets.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }}'

      steps:
        - name: Ubuntu Update / Upgrade / Reboot (back-end)
          shell: bash
          run: |
            BACKEND_HOST_SERVER_SH_SCRIPT=' \
            sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt update && sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt upgrade -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"; \
            sleep 5; \
            sudo reboot || true; \
            ';
            echo "${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_SSH_KEY }}" > id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
            chmod 600 id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
            ssh -v -t -t -i id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem -o ConnectTimeout=300 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }} "$BACKEND_HOST_SERVER_SH_SCRIPT"
            # rm id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
            echo "Status check: Reboot initiated.";
            sleep 60;
            # Verify if the server is back online
            # until ping -c 1 ${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }} & > /dev/null; do
            #   echo "Server not yet available, retrying in 15 seconds...";
            #   sleep 15;
            # done;
            # echo "Status check: Server is back online.";
            echo 'Waiting for server to come back online...';
            until ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }} 'echo "Server is back online"'; do
              echo "Server not yet available, retrying in 30 seconds...";
              sleep 30;
            done
            echo 'Status check: Server is back online, proceeding with the workflow.';
            rm id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
            
        - name: Docker - Install
          shell: bash
          run: |
            BACKEND_HOST_SERVER_SH_SCRIPT=' \
            sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common; \
            curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg; \
            echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null; \
            sudo apt install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io; \
            ';
            echo "${{ secrets.CONFIG_SERVER_SSH_KEY }}" > id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
            chmod 600 id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
            ssh -v -t -t -i id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }} "$BACKEND_HOST_SERVER_SH_SCRIPT"
            rm id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
            echo "Status check: Docker and dependencies installed successfully.";
```

I had to modify `apt upgrade -y` part because of the prompts it would be stuck on.

However, seems like the runner is encountering an error after reboot and can't continue to the next steps. The error looks something like this:

```sh
NEEDRESTART-VER: 3.5
NEEDRESTART-KCUR: 6.***.***-1***17-aws
NEEDRESTART-KEXP: 6.***.***-1***18-aws
NEEDRESTART-KSTA: 3
NEEDRESTART-SVC: acpid.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: chrony.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: cron.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: dbus.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: getty@tty1.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: networkd-dispatcher.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: packagekit.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: polkit.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: rsyslog.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: serial-getty@ttyS***.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: snapd.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: systemd-logind.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: unattended-upgrades.service
NEEDRESTART-SVC: user@1***.service
debug1: channel ***: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to *** closed by remote host.
Connection to *** closed.
Transferred: sent ***9***, received 1***584 bytes, in 83.*** seconds
Bytes per second: sent 34.9, received 1***9.3
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Anyone has an idea of how this can be done? Or if this type of approach is correct? Maybe splitting into 2 jobs? Initially, I wanted to put the "wait" part into a separate step, like this:

```yml
- name: Server - Wait for it to be Back Online (back-end)
  shell: bash
            
  run: |
    echo "${{ secrets.CONFIG_SERVER_SSH_KEY }}" > id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem
    chmod 600 id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem
    echo 'Waiting for server to come back online...';
    until ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }} 'echo "Server is back online"'; do
      echo "Server not yet available, retrying in 30 seconds...";
      sleep 30;
    done
    echo 'Status check: Server is back online, proceeding with the workflow.';
    rm id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
```

Server context:

- AWS / EC2
- Ubuntu
- Fresh install

**The solution with the help of Daniel B:**

The solution with the help of Daniel B:
How my YML file step ended up looking like.

```yml
steps:
  - name: Ubuntu Update / Upgrade / Reboot (back-end)
    shell: bash
    run: |
      BACKEND_HOST_SERVER_SH_SCRIPT=' \
      sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt update && sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt upgrade -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"; \
      ';
      echo "${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_SSH_KEY }}" > id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
      chmod 600 id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
      ssh -v -t -t -i id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem -o ConnectTimeout=300 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }} "$BACKEND_HOST_SERVER_SH_SCRIPT"
      ssh -v -t -t -i id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem -o ConnectTimeout=300 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }} "sudo reboot" || true;
      echo "Status check: Reboot initiated.";
      sleep 60;
      echo 'Status check: Waiting for server to come back online...';
      until ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }} 'echo "Server is back online"'; do
        echo "Status check: Server not yet available, retrying in 30 seconds...";
        sleep 30;
      done
      echo 'Status check: Server is back online, proceeding with the workflow.';
      rm id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem;
```

Comment: Probably a better fit for StackOverflow, and more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Ok - should I delete it?

Comment: I've flagged it to be migrated but yes, it'll probably be faster to just delete it and repost to SO.

Comment: I disagree that Stack Overflow is a good fit for this question. // Furthermore, I do not see anything out of the ordinary in that SSH log. This is simply what it looks like if you reboot the remote host.

Comment: Well - I wish it reboots the server without returning an error or stopping interrupting the execution of the next steps, but without turning errors off.

Comment: That wish will not be granted. I suggest you adapt your CI step instead. Maybe send the reboot command in a separate SSH connection where you _expect_ the error return code.

Comment: How about an arrangement in my step where I expect the error, but the script still continues to execute to the next step? Is there such a technique? I'm surprised this is not a common setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with these two statements:

```bash
BACKEND_HOST_SERVER_SH_SCRIPT=' \
            sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt update && sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt upgrade -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold"; \
            sleep 5; \
            sudo reboot || true; \
            ';
```

```bash
ssh -v -t -t -i id_rsa_server_private_key_temp.pem -o ConnectTimeout=300 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@${{ env.CONFIG_SERVER_BACKEND_IP }} "$BACKEND_HOST_SERVER_SH_SCRIPT"
```

You are attempting to fix the error with `reboot || true`, but this will not work. The error you get does not *really* come from the `reboot` command but from the reboot itself. It terminates all user sessions and also the SSH daemon. This means the SSH client will report an error because the connection gets closed somewhat ungracefully.

You must ignore that error, but you still want to fail if `apt` fails. So you need to split these across two SSH connections:

```bash
ssh $the_host "sudo apt …"
```

and

```bash
ssh $the_host "sudo reboot" || true
```

---

You can also allow the entire step to fail with `jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].continue-on-error`, but this is generally a bad idea.